Order of transformation & Imputing
I'm pre-processing my data for use in a linear regression model.
My features are highly skewed, and I would like to use a yeo-johnson transformation on some of my features, and a log transformation for others.
I have missing values in my features, and am unsure if I should undergo imputation before or after the transformation.
Thank you!
